# hg rollback on pushed commit changed phase to draft from public

Tags: mercurial

I accidentally did `hg rollback` on a commit that had been pushed upstream already. But to my surprise, instead of failing, it gave me the following response:

> repository tip rolled back to revision 5786 (undo push-response: https://blah-blah)

The `hg log` shows that it has changed back the phase from ***public*** to ***draft***.

```
[draft]  5786 feature/foo User some-commit-message (66 seconds ago) tip
[public] 5785 feature/foo User some-other-commit-message (5 minutes ago)
```

I tried `hg update -C` but doesn't seem to help. How can I restore the repository back to how it was?

**EDIT:** I did a hg push and it restored the phase back to public. So I'm where I'm. How can I stop mercurial from this behavior? Changing phase to draft wouldn't help *unpush* a change anyway!

Note: I'm using *Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.3.2)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn’t use `hg rollback` at all, it’s deprecated (as noted in `hg help rollback`). You’re under the impression that `rollback` undoes the last commit. That’s incorrect. Instead it rolls back the last *transaction*, which might not necessarily be a commit.

In the future, look into the [`histedit`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension) or [`evolve`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EvolveExtension) extensions for history rewriting.